# How to remove the default padding in Text Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a `Text` but even if I add the `includeFontPadding = false` it is adding an extra vertical padding as you can see here.

Without `includeFontPadding = false`

[image]

With `includeFontPadding = false`

[image]

I've also read this [`Style paragraph`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/text/style-paragraph) and tried to add this :

```
style = LocalTextStyle.current.merge(
    TextStyle(
        lineHeight = 32.em,
        platformStyle = PlatformTextStyle(
            includeFontPadding = false
        ),
        lineHeightStyle = LineHeightStyle(
            alignment = LineHeightStyle.Alignment.Bottom,
            trim = LineHeightStyle.Trim.None
            )
        )
)
```

I've also tried this `modifier=Modifier.wrapContentSize(unbounded = true)`

But doesn't work. My `Text` is like this :

```
Text(
    text = "EXAMPLE",
    fontSize = 36.sp,
    lineHeight = 32.sp,
    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
    maxLines = 1,
    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
    color = Color(0xFF2Fd322),
    textAlign = TextAlign.End,
    style = LocalTextStyle.current.merge(
        TextStyle(
            lineHeight = 32.em,
            platformStyle = PlatformTextStyle(
                includeFontPadding = false
            ),
            lineHeightStyle = LineHeightStyle(
                alignment = LineHeightStyle.Alignment.Bottom,
                trim = LineHeightStyle.Trim.None
            )
        )
    ),
    modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 8.dp)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't post comments (reputation must be >50), so I'm posting my comment here. In my opinion the vertical spacing **must** be there as there are letters like Ä, É, Ê, etc. You would have to move the whole textView up a bit.